# How to write a method that accepts stacks and queues?

Tags: java, generics, methods, stack, queue

So I have this really large method I wrote. If it's given a stack, it will return a stack. If it's given a queue, it will return a queue. It uses a lot of recursion, and it accepts a queue/stack and returns that same queue/stack modified accordingly.

I don't want to copy/paste my method just so I can change the type used inside, so is there any way I can make this generic? As in, it will accept any old collection and play with it? I tried just using Collection, but the trouble with that is it doesn't have a .remove() I can use with the stack/queue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the Javadoc of Stack states that a Deque is preferable. You might want to omit Stack altogether, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Collection but then have special case handling just around your remove operations. Of course you'll have to figure out what to do when you get a collection that's not one of the two.

```
if (myCollection instanceof Queue) {
    ((Queue)myCollection).remove();
} else if (myCollection instanceof Stack) {
    ((Stack)myCollection).remove(thingy);
} else {
    // Oops! Now what?
}
```

Comment: You can implement this internally, but restrict the public API to only allow you to pass in a Queue or a Stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot goto10, and everyone else who answered. This ended up working perfectly for my purposes. I just put this into a method and made another one for inserting, and it worked fine on a generic collection. One small detail, it's instanceof, not instanceOf (i.e. the O is not capitalized). Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Make your method private, and create two public methods: one which takes a stack and one which takes a queue. have each of these methods cast and return the result of calling the private method. That way you avoid repetition while still having specific method signatures.

Comment: The trouble is that the private method only accepts stacks as of now, and I'm wondering how I'll get it to accept a queue as well, and just called .remove() and .add() on it, since both Queue and Stack have those methods in Java. Basically what type should that large method accept for me to be able to give it stacks and queues, and what cast would I need to use on those stacks and queues?

Comment: @user999674: It depends largely on what your method actually does. Since Queues and Stacks are optimized for different actions, you may want to restrict the input to just one or the other, or even just require that a `List` be provided instead. You could also abstract out the non-specific logic into another method and pass it some kind of wrapper that knows how to add and remove items on the underlying items. The possibilities are pretty vast, and you haven't provided enough information to give you a really good answer. I just answered the question as it was originally posed.

Comment: I appreciate the help, this really is a good way of doing it, but considering the way the removals and additions are done, it really does seem to require a statement that first asks if it's a stack or a queue, as goto10 posted.

Answer (score 1):

Queue and Stack both have a remove() method, but the method is not the same.  Because of this, Java will need to know which of those methods to call when compiling the code.  You will need to have 2 separate methods.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an interface that has the operations you need from both Stack and Queue, since you want to use recursion/operations upon both.

This new interface would have two concrete classes that would rely on instances of Stack and Queue underneath, then polymorphism would to the magic.

You can always have a method for 'getUnderlyingCollection()' so you could have the actual Stack or Queue, after the proper cast, but attain to polymorphic operations would make your recursive algorithm more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean `java.util.Stack` and `java.util.Queue`. `Queue` defines its own [`remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove%28%29) method. `Stack` inherits its `remove(...)` methods from [`java.util.Vector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), so I assume you actually mean [`pop()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop%28%29)?

Two ways spring to mind:

- Provide two public method overloads which both call a private method with two parameters, one of which is always null.
- Define an interface with the common methods you need, with an anonymous inner class definition in each of two private methods (or a full concrete class definitions if they're sufficiently large).

Which you should choose depends on how many ugly conditional method calls you will need to do internally. An OO-purist would prefer the interface implementation regardless. :-)